# Printing in Python shell with " quotations instead of '

Tags: python, printing, format

I am trying to print a list in python with the " quotation marks instead of ' quotations marks.

E.g. What I am getting `myList = ['a','b','c','d']`
What I want to get `myList = ["a","b","c","d"]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: I am trying to take that list and use it somewhere else that doesn't accept the ' quotations it specifically asks for ".

Comment: I think you are mistaken somewhere.  There is no difference between " and '

Comment: Are you trying to produce JSON or something? If you want JSON, you should use a [JSON dumper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: @Simon For what I am doing the is a difference for some reason.

Comment: So for your list to json `print(json.dumps(myList))`

Answer (score 3):

You could do that using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json

myList = ['a','b','c','d']

out = json.dumps(myList)
print(out)
# ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is with `json` (because that happens to be the format JSON uses):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

*Here is some insight on how you could do it in pure python:*

The built in `__repr__` method of the `list` class is just calling `__repr__` on each of the elements...  in this case `str`.

`str.__repr__` has the behavior of using single quotes.  There is no (straightforward) way to change this.

You can roll your own type with it's own `__repr__` function to do it easily enough...

```
class mystr(str):
  def __repr__(self):
     return '"' + str.__repr__(self)[1:-1].replace('"', r'\"') + '"'


yourlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# convert your list in place
for i,v in enumerate(yourlist):
  yourlist[i] = mystr(v)

print(yourlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own string subclass whose representation uses `"` characters:

```
class MyStr(str):
    # Special string subclass to override the default representation
    # method. Main purpose is to prefer using double quotes and avoid hex
    # representation on chars with an ord() > 128
    def __repr__(self):
        quotechar = '"'
        rep = [quotechar]
        for ch in self:
            # Control char?
            if ord(ch) < ord(' '):
                # remove the single quotes around the escaped representation
                rep += repr(str(ch)).strip("'")
            # Does embedded quote match quotechar being used?
            elif ch == quotechar:
                rep += "\\"
                rep += ch
            # Else just use others as they are.
            else:
                rep += ch
        rep += quotechar
        return "".join(rep)


myList = ['a','b','c','d']
print(myList)  # -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print([MyStr(element) for element in myList])  # -> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way obviously is to solve it using json:

```
import json
print('myList = ', json.dumps(myList))
```

But another approach on solving it without using any additional library is this

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d']

print('myList = ', end='[')
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if i != 0:
        print(', \"' + myList[i], end='\"')
    else:
        print('\"' + myList[i], end='\"')
print(']')
```